# Rails 4 - rake db:seed NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

After successfully ran `rake db:migrate`, trying to run `rake db:seed --trace` but getting peculiar error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`.

Not exactly sure what the issue is. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

```
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:74: warning: circular argument reference - reflection
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord4.1.1/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:78: warning: circular argument reference - reflection
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord4.1.1/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:82: warning: circular argument reference - reflection
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord4.1.1/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:101: warning: circular argument reference - reflection
rake aborted!

NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:79:in `cached_counter_attribute_name'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:75:in `has_cached_counter?'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:83:in `update_counter'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:65:in `insert_record'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:522:in `block (2 levels) in concat_records'

#db/seeds.rb

 APP_KEYWORDS = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/db/app_keywords.yml")
 User.create(email: 'name@name.com', password: 'passwrd', password_confirmation: 'passwrd')
 User.create(email: 'name@name.com', password: 'psswrd', password_confirmation: 'psswrd')
 User.create(email: 'name@name.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password')
 User.create(email: 'name@name.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password')

 APP_KEYWORDS["app"].each do |key,value|
   app = App.find_or_create_by(name:key.downcase)
   value.each do |val|
     app.app_keywords.find_or_create_by(keyword:val.downcase)
   end
 end

 ["admin","moderator","venue_editor","user"].each do |role|
    Role.find_or_create_by(name:role)
 end

 user = User.first
 user.add_role :admin
```

Comment: Can you please post your `db/seeds.rb` file?

Comment: Well I'd be looking to see if my new migration(s) / models matched up with the data I was seeding.

Comment: You probably don't have to post the whole seeds.rb.  Find the line where the seeding fails. It's probably trying to create an object that depends on another object that you haven't yet created. Just change the order in which you seed your objects to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Following the issue: https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/issues/380

Try update for rails 4.1.2 version

Comment: Try to avoid link-only answers and put the information in the link as answer here.

Comment: @Prudhvi understood!